# Enabling/Disabling buttons; button never enables (visual studio)

Tags: if-statement, visual-studio-2015

Current code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Gold = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim Silver = CInt(TextBox2.Text) / 100
    Dim Copper = CInt(TextBox3.Text) / 10000
    Dim Result = (Gold + Silver + Copper) * 0.85
    Label1.Text = Result & " Gold"

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If (TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text = "") Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

How come whenever I start the program, and I enter numbers into `textbox1`, `textbox2`, and `textbox3` the button does not get enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `TextChanged` handlers to `TextBox1`,`TextBox2`,`TextBox3`. If text any of them changes, then you need to do you check from `Form1_Load`:

```
    If (TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text = "") Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
```

Ideally, write a private method to do the above code, and just call it from each of the TextBox handlers.  Just a good practice.

Comment: Thank you, this helped out!

Answer (score 0):

Because `Form1_Load()` is executed only once before you even entered the numbers.

Comment: How would I work around this, that it checks it every time? Simply put the `If` statement into the `Button1_Click`?